# nullpointer in Ksession when i add drools to existing system

Tags: java, drools, kie

I'm trying to add a drools part to an existing java system .. but probably i'm doing something wrong  ( i'm very newbie)... 
I added a kmodule.xml file to the classpath so done

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns = "http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
     <kbase name = "rules" packages = "rules">
 <ksession name = "ksession-rules" />
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

a sample.drl file so done

```
package com.xxx.drools
   declare Record
       field1: String @key
       field2: String @key
       field3: String @key
   end
   rule "CHECK_EVENT"
   When
         record: Record (field1 not in (1,46,25,26,264,6,9,13,44,73,125,130))
    then
         System.out.println ("blah blah blah");
   end
```

and in the java code

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
FactType amarecord = kSession.getKieBase().getFactType( "com.xxx.drools",
            "Record" );
```

The problem is a null pointer in the last line because  kSession is null.
Does anyone know how to help me? thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Package declaration in kmodule and drl file do not correspond.

Either change in sample drl

`package com.xxx.drools`
to
`package rules`

or change in kmodule.xml

`<kbase name = "rules" packages = "rules">` to `<kbase name = "rules" packages = "com.xxx.drools">`